# Save .docm to NEW .docx WITHOUT converting active document

Tags: vba, ms-word, docx

I use this .docm file (quotation and advice) over and over again, this .docm file itself keeps getting better every day as I am adding new information to it. For every new project I copy the last one used so I always use the most updated version.

If I send this to a client I use a macro to save and convert to PDF. All safe and sound.

Some clients request having a MS Word file for easy copy/paste into their own MS Word files. This is where stuff goes wrong: sending the client the original .docm file means I am sending them the macro's as well. Of course I do use a password to protect the VBA project but still... I just would like to send only the contents of the .docm file, not the file itself.

Furthermore, I have edit the .docm file with an XML editor to have some ribbon buttons as well. Also this I do not want to send over to the client.

Last but not least: the original .docm file contains a .PNG image (a signature handwritten by pen) which I would like to remove from the .docx file that is to be sent.

To solve my first and second 'problem' I guess I need to create an empty .docx file first and then copy and paste all from one to another. But the third (remove the PNG file) I am unaware of any options to do so.

A bit of research brought me up to this StackOverflow item:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64160234/ms-word-vba-to-save-docm-to-docx-without-converting-active-document](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".") - 1) & ".docx"
```

The line above does not use a new/blanc .docm file hence the ribbon items get copied.

The goal is that all dialogs may be passed, just save as .docx under the same name in the same folder.

I have record a macro to see if there would be any clou as to deleting the .PNG file but too bad that does not seem to give me any help.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Documents.Add Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
    Windows("MyDocument.docm").Activate
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Document1").Activate
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Windows("MyDocument.docm").Activate
    Windows("Document1").Activate
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    ActiveDocument.Save
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\MyPath\"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
        "C:\MyPath\MyDocument.docx", _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

But the code does allow me to have a clean/blanco .docx file without macro's and/or ribbon buttons.

Maybe the .PNG image does need to be named or given an ID of any kind? So it can be found by coding.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you were using Word correctly you wouldn't have this issue. Save your document as a Word template (.dotm) then create your new documents from that. All the code and ribbon XML will stay in the template.

Comment: The signature should be an `InlineShape` in a paragraph of its own, presumably at the end of the document. For example, if in the last para but one `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Previous.Range.InlineShapes(1).Delete`

Comment: Hi Timothy,

I have been struggling with template files (.dotx) because they tend to always save somewhere where I do not wand it. But I guess that needs better understanding from my side.

I will think about a .dotm solution. This however is not easy because my docm file pulls the filename (without extension) into the document. When starting in a dotm file there is no documentname.

Anyway, thanks.